# Elasticsearch nested query is returned all the nested list

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a model with that have a nested field `events` with a field `team_id`. These nested events could be huge and I would like to do few things on it.

1. Return only events with a specific `team_id` which is not doing with the query below which returns all the events
2. Use `inner_hits` to sort, limit the size and offset, also tried by sending the `size` and `from` params with no luck

I'm using `elasticsearch 5` in Ruby

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits

```
Model.search(
        query: {
          bool:{
            must: [
              { match: { "_id":  "zzzzzzz" }},
              nested: {
                path: "events",
                query: {
                          match: { "events.team_id":  "sdlfjslasdfj" }
                },
                inner_hits: {}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `elasticsearch-api` gem to get it working
`https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-api`

```
response = client.search index: 'index_name',
                           body: {
                             "_source": false,
                              "query": {
                                "nested": {
                                  "path": "events",
                                  "query": {
                                    "bool": {
                                      "must":[
                                        {"match": {"events.team_id": "xyz"}},
                                        {"match": {"_id": "sdlfjslasdfj"}}
                                      ]
                                    }
                                   },
                                   "inner_hits": {
                                     "size": 10,
                                     "from": 0,
                                     "sort": [{ "events.starts_at": "asc" }]
                                   }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
```